# Setting coordinates for Google Maps panel

Tags: google-maps, visualization

I want to put the Gmaps in my panel. The map doesn't work correctly and isn't centered on the point LatLang defined by me.

I have to use `<article class="panel>...</article> "` but maybe is in conflict with this.

what's wrong in this?

HTML code:

```
<article id="work_map" class="panel">
    <div id="map" style="height: 800px; width: 800px; margin:0 auto;"></div>
</article>
```

JS code:

```
function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(39.184791, 16.324256); // centro della mappa
    var primo = new google.maps.LatLng(39.184791, 16.324256); // segnapunto
    var secondo = new google.maps.LatLng(39.320035, 16.245327); // segnapunto
    // definizione della mappa
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 5,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.BOTTOM_CENTER}
    }
    mymap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
    // definizione segnapunto
    var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: primo,
        map: mymap,
        title:"Primo Marker!"
    });
    var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: secondo,
        map: mymap,
        title:"Secondo Marker!"
    });
}
```

Any solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please go through the online documentation of markers by google in the following link

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers

For sample refer the link http://www.svennerberg.com/2009/07/google-maps-api-3-markers/